# Запись данных в файл с помощью file_put_contents

Tags: php, html

Помогите правильно записать данные в файл finance.txt

```
<?php echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);

$filename = 'finance.txt';

file_put_contents ($filename, FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: http://php.net/file_put_contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почти всё верно, но только нужно сначала сериализовать массив `$_POST`

```
$data = serialize($_POST);
$filename = 'finance.txt';
file_put_contents($filename, $data);
// Чтобы достать данные
$file_data = unserialize(file_get_contents($filename));
```

Comment: спасибо. у меня была ошибка в правах доступа к файлу. поэтому, когда я пытался записывать в finance.txt свой массив $_POST - выдавало ошибку.